# How To sign in to Applemusic With Python Using Chrome Driver With Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, apple-music

I am trying to write a code using Python with selenium that will login to Applemusic.

1. Should open this URL: https://music.apple.com/login

2. After which the sign in Frame would pop up, I want to be able to input the AppleID (say example@gmail.com) with password say (Apple2020)
3. I want to be able to open a particular song url or playlist link so that I can manually play the songs.

My code so far:

```
from time import sleep
import Password
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
class Applemusic:
 
def __init__(self, username):
driver = webdriver.Chrome()


    driver.get("https://music.apple.com/login")
    sleep(20)
    for a in username:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "aid-auth-widget-iFrame")))
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "account_name_text_field"))).send_keys(a)
    sleep (10)
    password = "Apple2020"
    for i in password:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "password_text_field"))).send_keys(i)

Applemusic('example@gmail.com')
```

This is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/mike/Documents/Python/Applemusic.py", line 21, in 
> Applemusic('example@gmail.com')   File "/Users/mike/Documents/Python/Applemusic.py", line 14, in **init**
> WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,
> "aid-auth-widget-iFrame")))   File
> "/Users/mike/Documents/Python/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py",
> line 80, in until
> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

I don't know what I'm not doing right. My python knowledge is just average, I would appreciate if anyone can help me achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Apple ID* field is within nested `<iframe>` elements so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the **parent** *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the **child** *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://music.apple.com/login')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='/includes/commerce/authenticate?product=music']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title^='Sign In with your Apple']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#account_name_text_field"))).send_keys("Tycoonstory@apple.com")
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://music.apple.com/login')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, '/includes/commerce/authenticate?product=music')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@title, 'Sign In with your Apple')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='account_name_text_field']"))).send_keys("Tycoonstory@apple.com")
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: apple]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)