# How to write appropriate Xpath to locate text value

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I am trying to use python, selenium and xpath to grab the text $0.180 in the following block of HTML,

```
<div class="wlp-values-div">
  <span class="wlp-last-price-span">$0.180</span>
```

This code is deep into a websites HTML and I tried to use the following Xpath to locate it:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://smallcaps.com.au/stocks/?symbol=AWJ")
time.sleep(3)
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()

ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='wlp-values-div']/span[@class='wlp-last-price-span']")
```

But I receive the error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='wlp-values-div']/span[@class='wlp-last-price-span']"}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Probably the problem is the element is in a frame.

Comment: I have not, I'm not sure how to do that and format it with xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *last price* field is within nested `<iframe>` elements so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the **parent** *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the **child** *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be visible*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://smallcaps.com.au/stocks/?symbol=AWJ')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "svg[data-name='close']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#wl-summary")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.wl-quote-frame")))
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.wlp-last-price-span"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
    driver.quit()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://smallcaps.com.au/stocks/?symbol=AWJ')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg' and @data-name='close']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='wl-summary']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='wl-quote-frame']")))
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='wlp-last-price-span']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
    driver.quit()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
    $0.190
  ```

> You can find a detailed relevant discussion in [How To sign in to Applemusic With Python Using Chrome Driver With Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65440796/how-to-sign-in-to-applemusic-with-python-using-chrome-driver-with-selenium/65442397#65442397)

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: wow thats incredibly clear! ive just had a chance to read this and cant thank you enough! The way you can breakdown a complex topic into such simple terms is a credit to your own abilities and knowledge

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe class="wl-summary" id="wl-summary" src="https://cloud.weblink.com.au/clients/smallcaps/summary/summary.aspx?symbol=AWJ&amp;" width="100%" height="25" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" style="height: 1077px;"></iframe>
<iframe class="wl-quote-frame" src="quoteFrame.aspx?symbol=AWJ&amp;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="1" style="height: 177px;"></iframe>
```

It's in a double nested iframe so you have to switch to it. This also has the appropriate waits instead of using time.sleep() and hoping the elements load. It also clicks the popup to get out of the way and prints the spans text.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://smallcaps.com.au/stocks/?symbol=AWJ")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#tve_editor > div'))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CLASS_NAME, 'wl-summary')))
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CLASS_NAME, 'wl-quote-frame')))
elem=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.wlp-last-price-span')))
print(elem.text)
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I get the following syntax error when trying to use your code

SyntaxError: invalid syntax



<iframe class="wl-summary" id="wl-summary" src="https://cloud.weblink.com.au/clients/smallcaps/summary/summary.aspx?symbol=AWJ&amp;" width="100%" height="25" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" style="height: 1077px;"></iframe>