# I m unable to locate the frame - tabFrame from the below screenshot

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I'm unable to locate the frame - **tabFrame** from the attached screenshot, whereas I was able to locate **outlookFrame**. I used:

```
driver.switch_to.frame('outlookFrame')
```

But when I use:

```
driver.switch_to.frame('tabFrame')
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: can you please share the url?

Answer (score 0):

As the desired elements is within nested [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478) elements so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the **parent** *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the **child** *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get("http://web_page")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"outlookFrame_cssSelector")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name='tabFrame']")))
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get("http://web_page")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"outlookFrame_xpath")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@name='tabFrame']")))
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [How to write appropriate Xpath to locate text value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66217454/how-to-write-appropriate-xpath-to-locate-text-value/66222874#66222874)
- [How To sign in to Applemusic With Python Using Chrome Driver With Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65440796/how-to-sign-in-to-applemusic-with-python-using-chrome-driver-with-selenium/65442397#65442397)