# How do I switch to a frame and select an element in the frame?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, frames, frameset

I am trying to select the frame 'mainFrame'.

The page source is :

```
<frameset rows="89,*" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0">
    <frame name="topFrame" scrolling="NO" noresize src="inc-webpage/b-topnav.asp">
        <frameset rows="*,20" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0">
            <frameset cols="175,*" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0">
                <frame name="leftFrame" scrolling="AUTO" noresize src="inc-webpage/b-sidenav-3.asp">
                <frame name="mainFrame" src="b-default.asp">
            </frameset>
            <frame name="bottomFrame" scrolling="NO" noresize src="inc-webpage/b-footer.asp">
        </frameset>
</frameset>
<noframes>
```

The element I wish to select is in 'mainFrame'. Therefore my code is:

```
time.sleep(5)    
driver.switch_to.frame("mainFrame");
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'I Agree')]").click()
```

Yes. time.sleep() is not ideal so I'm just using it for the time being.

Here is the HTML for the element I wish to select within 'mainFrame':

```
<input type="button" value="I Agree" 
class="btn" onmouseover="blueBtnOver(this)" onmouseout="blueBtnOut(this)" 
onclick="javascript:location.href='b-3c-pLessonBooking.asp?limit=pl'" style="background: rgb(0, 102, 204);">
```

Currently getting this Error:

> NoSuchFrameException(frame_reference)
> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: mainFrame

I am an absolute beginner. The `driver.find_element_by_xpath` is probably wrong

Also why do some websites use frames//framesets while others use iframes and some don't use either?

Comment: Button `I Agree` is not inside the frame you have posted. You need to check in DOM and parent of that button if there any frame?? it should be like `<frame>#document  <html>button element</html></frame>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically wait for the frame switch to it and then click the input with matching value I agree.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("mainFrame"))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='I Agree']").click()
```

Comment: The code returns a time out error ; it probably couldn't find the frame

Comment: Is the page taking a long time to load>

Comment: nope; i have an ethernet connection and i even set the driver.sleep(30) just to make sure

Answer (score -1):

The desired element is nested within multiple `<frame>` elements so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the **parent** *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the **child** *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"frame[name='topFrame']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"frame[name='mainFrame']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.btn[value='I Agree']"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//frame[@name='topFrame']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//frame[@name='mainFrame']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='btn' and @value='I Agree']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [How To sign in to Applemusic With Python Using Chrome Driver With Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65440796/how-to-sign-in-to-applemusic-with-python-using-chrome-driver-with-selenium/65442397#65442397)