# How do I type login credentials using Selenium and Python within kingdoms.com?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

I tried a few websites don't have a problem. "`baseURL`" tried a lot of time.

```
driver.find the class element
```

can't get. Anyone can help?

Click this link below and inside the login page ...
which one to use ??

Code trials:

```
PATH = "D:\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)



baseURL = "https://www.kingdoms.com/#logout"
driver = get(baseURL)

print(driver.title)

driver.find_element_by_xpath
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an nested iframe in that page, so you have to switch to iframe and again to iframe, and then you can `send the keys` to email address input field.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://www.kingdoms.com/#logout")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "cmpbntyestxt"))).click()
except:
    pass
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe.mellon-iframe")))
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src*='https://mellon-t5.traviangames.com/account/logout']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='email']"))).send_keys('Mario@gmail.com')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']"))).send_keys("marios password")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='submit']"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: many many thanks.I learned a lot, and the last one login button, why i using this one  . it showing me Error
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Log in").click()

Comment: Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Log in"}
  (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.63)
  File "C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\learnpy\travian.py", line 22, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Log in").click()

Comment: because i want to click Login button

Comment: any idea send Login key ?

Comment: @MarioHooi : Updated above, check it out, you will have to give right credentials to make this to work

Comment: i add one more line click ENTER __
`wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']"))).send_keys(usrPwd)`  
`WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']"))).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`

Comment: hmm.. it would cause you are simulating the enter keys, which is a different way, But I tried my code as well in my local machine and it worked.

Comment: but i am confuse a bit , some solution is
` (Keys.RETURN) ``(Keys.ENTER)`

Comment: Both are to press Enter button `(Keys.RETURN)` or `(Keys.ENTER)`

Answer (score 0):

The desired fields are within nested `<iframe>` elements so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the **parent** *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the **child** *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.kingdoms.com/#logout')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.cmpboxbtn.cmpboxbtnyes]"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.mellon-iframe")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://mellon-t5.traviangames.com/account/logout/applicationDomain']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='email']"))).send_keys("Mario@Hooi.com")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password']").send_keys("MarioHooi")
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.kingdoms.com/#logout')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='cmpboxbtn cmpboxbtnyes']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='mellon-iframe']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://mellon-t5.traviangames.com/account/logout/applicationDomain')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='email']"))).send_keys("Mario@Hooi.com")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']").send_keys("MarioHooi")
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [How To sign in to Applemusic With Python Using Chrome Driver With Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65440796/how-to-sign-in-to-applemusic-with-python-using-chrome-driver-with-selenium/65442397#65442397)

Comment: i tried this 2 code..it showing ERROR
Using CSS_SELECTOR:

Exception has occurred: TimeoutException
Message: 
  File "C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\learnpy\travian.py", line 24, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.cmpboxbtn.cmpboxbtnyes]"))).click()

Using XPATH:
Exception has occurred: TimeoutException
Message: 
  File "C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\learnpy\travian.py", line 32, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='cmpboxbtn cmpboxbtnyes']"))).click()